# Cannot connect to Oracle Database with Power Query

Tags: microsoft-excel, odbc

I'm trying to import data from Oracle to Excel. I was hoping to find Oracle DB on the drop down under Get Data as see online:

[image]

That picture not being there I hit the [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-to-an-oracle-database-power-query-d7fbd231-a705-4eb7-83b3-a66bfb678395) explaining I should install **32-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (12.1.0.2.4)**.

After doing this, I could not see the drop down. However, I read [elsewhere](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9525905800346989316) that it could be accessed from the Other Sources > From OBDC:

[image]

I went through my Windows Admin Tools > ODBC Data Source Administrator and there I added a new Microsoft ODBC for Oracle Setup.

My database now appeared in the ODBC database choice drop down. I call for the query and... I get two errors:

First a Windows error:

> "The Oracle(tm) client and networking components were not found.
>   Thesec components are supplied by Oracle Corportation and are part of
>   the Oracle Version 7.3 (or greater) client software installation. You
>   will be unable to use these drivers until these components have been
>   installed"

Then power query error:

> "ODBC: ERROR [IM004] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's
>   SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_ENV failed"

**Update:** When running Excel as an Administrator, I am only getting the second error message.

I've looked up my environment variables, as I've seen elsewhere that they may be related to this issue:

[image]

So now I'm a litte confused and don't understand what this means and what I've done wrong. Other posts here didn't point to the right direction (I think).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to connect to the Oracle database.

1. I had to install some pre-requisites, namely the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable packages x_64 and x_86.
2. I followed the steps in this document: https://manjaro.site/how-to-install-oracle-odbc-driver-on-windows-10/

It worked like a charm and I also can connect to MySql as bonus.